# Resource order in Grails

Tags: grails, resources

I have several resource modules defined in ApplicationResources.groovy similar to this:

```
modules = { 
  First{
    resource url:'js/code1.js'
    resource url:'js/code2.js'
  }

  MiddleA{
    dependsOn 'First'
    resource url:'js/code3.js'
    resource url:'js/code4.js'
  }

  MiddleB{
    dependsOn 'First'
    resource url:'js/code5.js'
    resource url:'js/code6.js'
  }

  Last{
    resource url:'js/code7.js'
    resource url:'js/code8.js'
  }
}
```

I would like the resources to be loaded in the order following order:

- *First*
- Either *MiddleA* or *MiddleB* depending on a certain condition.
- *Last*

I cannot use `dependsOn` in *Last* because it may depend on either *MiddleA* or *MiddleB*, but not both (*MiddleA* and *MiddleB* should never be included in the same page). However, I find that in the HTML generated by Grails, the `script` tag for *Last* comes always before the one for *MiddleA/B*. I've tried a number of ways of forcing the order I want (including bundling in several ways) but to no avail. I have run out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I managed to make it work, but only in the ugliest way possible. As it turns out, if I rename the *Last* module to *zzzzzz*, it's loaded in last place the way I want it to. To make it even more mindboggling, it has to be six z's, it won't work with five z's, or seven z's, or six x's, or any other word I've tried. Needless to say, I don't feel particularly comfortable with this weird workaround.

Comment: I assume having two different `last` bundles is out of the question?

Comment: Yes, as it's rather big and I'd like to keep it DRY.